# 301 redirection from index.php only on main page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect /index.php to the main site without index but only on the main page.
I use this code in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the problem is that in Admin panel there is routing that needs index.php for pages to work properly. And this rule is deleting index.php everytime it appears on any page.
I tried adding line like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/AdminPanel/index\.php.*$
```

before RewriteRule but it doesn't change anything.
Hope you will help.

Comment: I combined the last mentioned line in many ways but I can't get it to work as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.*` from your regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Seems to work now, thank you very much! I will flag this as accepted in 10 minutes :)